# get vim to search the python path

Tags: python, vim

I'm using vim as my primary editor with python files; I'd like to be able to easily open python files.

As an example: I'm looking at a particular module `A.py`, in it I see the line `import funkyModule`, I want to edit that module so I just type in the command `:pyed funkyModule` and the  `pyed` vim-command automatically finds the file `funkyModule.py` (or `funkyModule/__init__.py`) where ever it occurs on the python path.

This capability is modeled on the capabilities if the `ipython` shell, where

`In [#]: edit funkyModule`

does what I've just described.

Comment: Try http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2473

Comment: Or http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3752